# Trouble with math in java

Tags: java, math

It's been a long day for me and I don't know if I can't do second grade math or if I'm doing something wrong in terms of how to do math in java.  I'm not new to java, I started about a year and a half ago, but like I said, it's been a long day.

Here is my code:

```
System.out.println(5 / 150 * 100);
```

I expect to get something like "3.3333" or at least "3", but I get "0" instead.  Why is that and how do I fix it?

Comment: Try `5.0` or `(float) 5`. The problem might be related to Int vs. Float conversion .

Comment: 5 / 150 = 0. 0 * 100 = 0. You have integer division which only returns the integer portion of the result.

Answer (score 1):

Your second grade math is perfectly correct. However, `5 / 150 = 0.03` will become zero because its type is `int`. Then multiplying 0 with 100 won't change anything.

Use floats or doubles and you'll get the right result. Which of these two you use, depends on your needs. If you need a very precise value (a freaking lot of 3s behind the point) use `double` because it has - as its name tells you - two times the precision of a `float`.

Answer (score -1):

All of your operand is `int` value and it will result in `int` value.

Try to change your operand to `float` value.

Try this:

```
System.out.println(5f / 150 * 100);
System.out.println(5 / 150f * 100);
```

Comment: It could be helpful to explain *why*.